# Bootstrap work with php dynamically for closing and reopen modal to remain input data original state

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am handling with some input text,radio,checkbox and select together with modal.

```
<script>
$(function(){ $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) { 
$("#myModal .modal-body").find('input:radio, input:checkbox').prop('checked', false); 
}) });
</script>

<a data-target="#myModal" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">
    Launch demo modal</a>
<div class="modal " id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
<input type="checkbox" name="ppp" value="12">

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If i check the checkbox, close the modal , the checkbox remain original state(uncheck) when reopen again (this is due to the js).This way works well for static page. If having a dynamic page, it wont work due to JS is targeting at

```
$('#myModal') -> data-target="#myModal"
```

Then for dynamic page example, I have the following coding.

```
echo '<table class="table table-hover">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th><th>Price</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
    ';
echo '</thead>';

foreach ($display->all_item as $iid => $row) {

    echo "<tr data-backdrop='static' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#".$iid."'>";

    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo "<td>";
        echo $display->all_item[$iid][$key]." ";
        echo "</td>";
   }



   echo "</tr>";
   require "update_item.php";
}
echo '</table>';
```

whenever user clicks on the table row, the modal will open base on the item_ID, it the JS coding wont work for such way.

```
$('#myModal') -> data-target='#".$iid."'
```

So my question is how to modify the JS coding to make it change dynamically for changing to something like this

```
$('#iid') -> data-target='#".$iid."'
```

For a clearer explaination , please refer to the screenshot.

[image]